# Elementary consequences of commuting limits and colimits over groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, category-theory, group-actions

In [this n-cat cafe](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/12/commuting_limits_and_colimits.html) post, it is proven that for finite groups $G,H$ of coprime order, $G$-colimits and $H$-limits commute. Later on the following theorem is mentioned:

**Theorem 1.** $H$-limits commute with $G$-colimits in $\mathsf{Set}$ iff no nontrivial quotient of $H$ is isomorphic to a subquotient of $G$.

On the [nlab page about commutativity of limits and colimits](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutativity+of+limits+and+colimits#taking_orbits_under_the_action_of_a_finite_group_commutes_with_cofiltered_limits), it's also mentioned that taking orbits under the action of a finite group commutes with cofiltered limits, i.e:

**Theorem 2.** Let $G$ be a finite group and $\mathsf C$ be a small cofiltered category. Let $F:\mathsf C\longrightarrow G\mathsf{Set}$ be a functor. Then $(\varprojlim F)/G\cong \varprojlim _{j\in F}(F(f)/G)$.

I'm reasonably familiar with category theory, but I've only ever taken one course on groups - a first semester course about finite groups. I'm curious whether one could derive from these commutation results some basic facts in the theory of (finite) groups.

> What kind of familiar elementary facts about (finite) groups can be derived from these results?

**Update:** This question has now been [crossposted to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219453/elementary-consequences-of-commuting-limits-and-colimits-over-groups).